# Font-Awesome not showing instead square showing in Spring framework

Tags: html, css, spring, font-awesome

I am working in Spring framework, where images, css and javascript files are loading properly. But when font-awesome css import font-awesome fonts it is not working. I have not done any spring configuration for resources.

I have attached my file layout and output below

```
<div class="text-center product_overlayIncrementBtn">
    <button class="btn btn-success product_overlayDecBtn">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-success product_overlayAddBtn">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

[image: See my files layout]
[image: Font-awesome output]

I searched and tried lot, but did not find what I'm doing wrong. Please help me out as I am trying from last 20 hours and still  have not succeeded.

Comment: Have you included font-awesome.css in your HTML file?

Comment: Yes i have. i have also include output screen shot. Please look into.

Comment: Please post HTML code for how you are calling these icons. It should be like ```<span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>```.

Comment: I have updated my question with html code.

Comment: Press **F12**, in console see if there are `404` errors. Also try clearing cache

Comment: Yes, there is 404 error for font awesome. but the path is correct as you can see in the question. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution. We just need to put into the web.xml file below code and program working correctly hurray....

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this into the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```